# On clicking the FCM notification the same link opens on multiple tabs

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

Does FCM service worker implementation not have the logic to find out if the same URL is already open? It opens the same URL (specified using click_action) on multiple tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library does have some basic logic to attempt to focus on a tab if it already has the tab currently open but this is limited to only tabs on the same origin (or domain) as the site that registered for push.

For example if your site is https://example.com, and you set the click_action was https://google.com, the click_action will always open a new tab because the web API's don't allow examining other origins.

However, if click_action is https://example.com/test and that tab / window was already open, the library will focus on that tab.

All that being said, it could be a bug, do you have an example of the click_action URL and the URL for your site?

Comment: Ah.. Got it. I think I was just testing with a different domain. And since you mentioned that APIs dont allow examining other origins, it opened a new tab every time I clicked the notification.

Comment: on a separate note, we currently use [data message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages) instead of notification message. Once we get the message, we use service worker showNotification to show the notification. But there is no way to specify click handler for this. I had to use custom SW and write a notificationclick event handler to do this. Do you think the library has plan to support the click handler for locally created messages using showNotification? [gist](https://gist.github.com/vibgy/0c5f51a8c5756a5c408da214da5aa7b0)

Comment: If you add a notificationclick event it will get called for your custom notification.

Comment: I updated the [gist](https://gist.github.com/vibgy/0c5f51a8c5756a5c408da214da5aa7b0) ... Its working well now for me with data messages... Do you mind taking a look at this gist? Have any recommendations?

Comment: Not working, I am sending notification from same domain and my click_action is also same URL, however i am using notification "payload" not "data" payload